# How to speed up callback during taking picture by Android Camera API

Tags: android, android-camera

I use Android Camera API (not Camera2) to take picture,  As we know, we take picture like these codes

```
 // Begin,,,
 camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // End,,,,
    }
 }
```

But I found that some devices take almost 300ms to receive callback data.

> (End time - Begin time = 300ms)

How can I shorten this time internal, how to speed up this process.

Comment: Choose a lower-resolution image. Speed here is largely dictated by hardware, which you do not control. The only thing that you can control would be how much work that hardware has to do.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make it faster in general.  It depends entirely on the individual device's hardware (speed of the sensor, speed of snapshot processing, speed of JPEG encode).

With the camera2 API, and a device at the FULL level, you are guaranteed to be able to capture full-resolution YUV images at 30fps. But not terribly many devices support this level of operation yet.

Many device makers also have custom camera API extensions to enable various zero shutter lag modes, which give fairly instant captures.  But again, those are device specific, generally undocumented, and only available on high-end devices for the most part.